# Get filename from Content-Disposition header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm currently checking for this header and if it's available, I'll try to get the filename from it. Question is, what is the best method to retrieve it? I understand that Content-Disposition header may appear with different parameters. Examples below:

```
Content-Disposition = "inline; filename=sample-file-123.pdf"
Content-Disposition = "attachment; filename="123.zip""
```

I'm only interested to get the filename.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a dedicated API for this: `URLResponse.suggestedFilename`

So if you are getting your header from a URLResponse you just call

```
let filename: String = response.suggestedFilename ?? "default"
```

and you're done. Note that despite what the documentation says, the return value is optional so you have to provide a default or force unwrap if you dare (I wouldn't).

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresponse/1415924-suggestedfilename):

> The method first checks if the server has specified a filename using the
> content disposition header. If no valid filename is specified using that mechanism,
> this method checks the last path component of the URL. If no valid filename can be
> obtained using the last path component, this method uses the URL's host as the filename.
> If the URL's host can't be converted to a valid filename, the filename "unknown" is used.
> In mose cases, this method appends the proper file extension based on the MIME type.
> This method always returns a valid filename.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something along the lines of this:

```
- (NSString *)getFilenameFrom:(NSString *)string {
    NSRange startRange = [string rangeOfString:@"filename="];

    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound && startRange.length != NSNotFound) {
        int filenameStart = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        NSRange endRange = [string rangeOfString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(filenameStart, [string length] - filenameStart)];
        int filenameLength = 0;

        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound && endRange.length != NSNotFound) {
            filenameLength = endRange.location - filenameStart;
        } else {
            filenameLength = [string length] - filenameStart;
        }

        return [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(filenameStart, filenameLength)];
    }
    return nil; //or return @"", whatever you like
}
```

You will have to check it as i made this in the browser (dont have access to xcode atm).

Comment: Thanks, I modified the answer above to cater for cases where the Content-Disposition header is sent, but without the filename parameter.

Comment: i corrected the above code to return file name without ' " " .. by the way thanks dragon112 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
+ (NSString *)filenameFromContentDispositionHeader:(NSString *)contentDispositionHeader {
  NSString *pattern = @"filename=\"(.*)\"";
  NSRegularExpression *regex =
      [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
  NSTextCheckingResult *result =
      [regex firstMatchInString:contentDispositionHeader
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, contentDispositionHeader.length)];
  NSRange resultRange = [result rangeAtIndex:0];

  if (resultRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
  } else {
    return [contentDispositionHeader substringWithRange:
        NSMakeRange(resultRange.location + 10, resultRange.length - 11)];
  }
}
```

Note that you'll need to modify the pattern if you can't be sure the filename is surrounded in double-quotes.